# confusing ESC Sound as soon as i move the sticks on transmitter

Tags: flight-controller, esc, transmitter, battery-cell

there is this confusing sound which pops out of the esc as soon as i move the sticks on the transmitter. This never happened before. Normally when i plug in my battery there appears a sound but this one is different and just comes up when touching the sticks.
What does this mean? Are there pages where i can check the meaning behind a sound?

Comment: If you enter the model number of the ESC into google, you should be able to find a manual which describes its operation and the various sounds.

Comment: Without further details on the sound(s) and specifics of the ESC, we can't really help figure it out.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I Don‘t really know why but these special sounds never appeared again. I haven‘t done anything beside restarting the whole system…